# Difference between :w and :w! in vi editor

Tags: vi

What difference does it make if I use **:w!** instead of **:w**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:w` will write current changes to the file from buffer
but if readonly flag is set then this write is refused in that case

use `:w!`

you can refer the  vim document here http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#writing

Answer (score 1):

Generally "!" in vi use to override i.e if u modified a readonly file then while saveing it using :w you will get message "E52 readonly opton is set use ! to override". you can use **:w!** to override the warning and your changes will be reflected in the file  (Note:If you are the owner of the file then only changes will be reflected,You can use chown to change owner).
If you want to close without saving the changes you can use **:q!**.
Some Other uses are like if you want to executes any 'cmd' as a shell command then you can **use :! 'cmd'** eg: :! ls will list files and folders in the currect directory.
Similarlly if you want to save and exit a readonly file use **:wq!**

You can say
:w is like a request.
:w! is like a order.

Answer (score 1):

`:w` stands for saving the file ---> only applicable if file has rwx permission.
and `:w!` stands for saving the file forcefully. ---> Useful when file has permission r-x permission

Answer (score 0):

You'll overwrite the file if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

w! overwrites the file and forces a write.   w will prompt you if you are attempting to overwrite the a file with the same name.